# rake: Lost rule-dependency when defining another dependency

Tags: rake, rule

I have a problem with a rule in combination with other file dependencies.

See the following minimal example:

```
require 'rake'

rule '.tex' do |tsk|
  puts "Create %s" % tsk.name
end
rule '.pdf' => '.tex' do |tsk|
  puts 'Create %s' % tsk.name
end

#~ file 'test.pdf' => 'include.tex'

task :default => 'test.pdf'
```

If I check the actions, everything is ok:

```
rake -n
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test.pdf (first_time)
** Invoke test.tex (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) test.tex
** Execute (dry run) test.pdf
** Execute (dry run) default
```

test.pdf depends on test.tex and everything would work correct (instead of the `puts`-statements I would define 'real' actions).

But if I uncomment `file 'test.pdf' => 'include.tex'` then I get to following result:

```
rake -n
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test.pdf (first_time)
** Invoke include.tex (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) include.tex
** Execute (dry run) test.pdf
** Execute (dry run) default
```

test.pdf depends on include.tex (correct), but the dependency from the rule is lost.

To get my example run, I must define a dependency `file 'test.pdf' => 'test.tex'` - but that rule should already be defined by the rule:

```
require 'rake'

file 'test.tex' do |tsk|
  puts "Create %s" % tsk.name
end
file 'include.tex' do |tsk|
  puts "Create %s" % tsk.name
end

rule '.pdf' => '.tex' do |tsk|
  puts 'Create %s' % tsk.name
end

file 'test.pdf' => 'test.tex'
file 'test.pdf' => 'include.tex'

task :default => 'test.pdf'
```

So my question: Is it possible to abstain from the obvious rule-based dependecy when I have additional depndecies?

Comment: The following seems to work: `rule '.pdf' => ['.tex', 'include.tex'] do |tsk|`.  However, i wonder how to add individual dependencies for just some of the targets.

Comment: @Alexey INteresting. Unfortunately differnt files may have different includes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rake/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Rules**
>
> When a file is named as a prerequisite, *but does not have a file task defined for it*, Rake will attempt to synthesize a task by looking at a list of rules supplied in the Rakefile.

So, it appears like this is not supported in the DSL.

However, there is a method `Rake::Application#enhance_with_matching_rule` that can add both the prerequisites and the actions from a rule to a task. You can call the method on your instance and supply the file name:

```rb
require 'rake'

rule '.tex' do |tsk|
  puts "Create %s" % tsk.name
end
rule '.pdf' => '.tex' do |tsk|
  puts 'Create %s' % tsk.name
end

file 'test.pdf' => 'include.tex'
Rake.application.enhance_with_matching_rule('test.pdf')

task :default => 'test.pdf'
```

I'm not sure if it's an improvement, but it seems to work:

```
$ rake -n
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test.pdf (first_time)
** Invoke include.tex (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) include.tex
** Invoke test.tex (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) test.tex
** Execute (dry run) test.pdf
** Execute (dry run) default
```